# How to change a parse's Facebook account custom fields

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am trying to enable login with a Facebook account for my new social app but I need to know how to change custom Facebook accounts fields in parse so I can know if a Facebook user already set up his account or not. I managed to do it with regular accounts but now with Facebook accounts
Here is my method:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("procceedToSetup", sender: self)

                // I need to change here a parse field named "doneSetUp" with a type of a bool to false.

            } else {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("procceedToApp", sender: self)

            }
        } else {

            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

        }
    }
```

When a Facebook user completes the setup he/she will press the complete button and it will change the variable "doneSetUp" to true, I do it so Facebook accounts won't exit the app in the middle of the setup and when they log in back they will access the app without setup.
By the way, I would like to know how can I access Facebook account fields I chose with the permissions array, such as country, profile picture, name, etc...

Thanks for all the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

Jeez, I found the reason.
forgot to put

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
```

at the end.